# How to get a specific key in an api request using any Flutter packages

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first question here

I run into a small problem, I was just testing the water with this API request:
[https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character](https://stackoverflow.com)

**I Need to know how I can get 'results' ONLY After making its model using Http or Dio ?**
Is there a way to skip the first key'info'?

I appreciate your help.

This block of code returns :

> 'errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr dioooooooooooo'

What should I change,please

[image: This is a screenshot of the code]

Answer (score 0):

you function having the return type `Future<List<Character>>` so in this case you have to convert that result to the `List<Character>` and to do so you have to use the `fromJson` method to parse the API Response.